# A question about reduciblility

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why a polynomial $f(x)＝2x^2+4$ is reducible over $\Bbb C$? Isn't 2 a unit on $\Bbb C$? Hop someone can explain it clearly. Thanks.

Comment: All polynomials reduce to linear factors over $\Bbb C$ because it's algebraically closed

Comment: what actually do you want to convey when you say "Isn't 2 a unit on $\mathbb{C}$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our polynomial factors for example as
$$2x^2+4=(2x-2\sqrt{2}i)(x+\sqrt{2}i).$$

**Remark:** It is true that $2x^2+4=2(x^2+2)$ does not prove reducibility, since $2$ is a unit.